# How to use conditional rendering with Vue.js slots?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs-slots

How can I use the result of a `v-if` to render two different components in Vue? If it matters, I'm also trying to do this while rendering a `TreeView` using `v-for`. Here's what I tried so far.

TreeView.vue:

```
<template>
    <span>
        <ul v-show="isOpen" v-if="isFolder">
            <p
                v-for="(child, index) in item.children"
                v-bind:item="child"
                v-bind:key="index"
                <span v-if="!child.isFolder">
                    <slot v-bind:individualBookmark="child"></slot>
                </span>
                <span v-else> 
                    <div v-bind:class="{bold: isFolder}" v-on:click="toggle" v-on:dblclick="makeFolder" v-on:contextmenu="rightClick">
                        {{ child.name }}
                        <span v-if="isFolder">[{{ isOpen ? '-' : '+' }}]</span>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </p>
        </ul>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TreeView",
  props: {
    item: Object
  },
  components: {
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      isOpen: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isFolder: function() {
      return this.item.children.length > 0;
      //return this.item.children && this.item.children.length;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      if (this.isFolder) {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
      }
    },
    makeFolder: function() {
      if (!this.isFolder) {
        this.$emit("make-folder", this.item);
        this.isOpen = true;
      }
    },
    rightClick: function() {
      alert("Right click action")
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**`App.vue`** (the `Bookmark` tag is a custom component I built that does **not** have the `isFolder` computed property):

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
      <TreeView v-slot:default="slotProps"
                v-bind:item="treeData"
                v-on:make-folder="makeFolder"
                v-on:add-item="addItem">
        <Bookmark v-bind="slotProps.individualBookmark"></Bookmark>
      </TreeView>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import Bookmark from './components/Bookmark.vue'
import TreeView from './components/TreeView.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        Bookmark,
        TreeView
    },

    data: function() {
        return {
            treeData : {
                    name: "My Tree",
                    children: [
                      { name: "hello" },
                      { name: "wat" },
                      {
                        name: "child folder 1",
                        children: [
                          {
                            name: "child folder",
                            children: [{ name: "hello" }, { name: "wat" }]
                          },
                          { name: "hello" },
                          { name: "wat" },
                          {
                            name: "child folder",
                            children: [{ name: "hello" }, { name: "wat" }]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
            }
          }
    },
    methods: {
        makeFolder: function(item) {
            Vue.set(item, "children", []);
            this.addItem(item);
        },
        addItem: function(item) {
            item.children.push({
              name: "new stuff"
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I run this, for some reason, the `v-if="!child.isFolder"` in TreeView.vue always evaluates to true so it renders the Bookmark component. Even in the case when the `v-if` should be evaluating to false like when given the "child folder 1" child object of `treeData`, it still evaluates to true. I have a feeling the problem is to do with how I'm using `<slot></slot>` in `TreeView.vue` but I'm not sure. Why is the `v-if` always evaluating to true and never false?

The problem may also have to do with how I wrote the `isFolder` property.

Comment: "you map the item prop inside the Treeview component and add that property" 

could you explain how to do this? I don't fully understand how to implement it in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a computed property called `computedChildren` inside the `Treeview` component which maps the item prop by adding `isFolder` property :

```
  computed: {
    isFolder: function() {
      return this.item.children.length > 0;
      //return this.item.children && this.item.children.length;
    },
   computedChildren(){
      return this.item.children.map(child=>{
           child.isFolder=child.children?child.children.length>0:false //this add the property isFolder

          return child
        })
    }
  },
```

Then loop through it as follows :

```
<p
 v-for="(child, index) in computedChildren"
...
```

For replacing the slot you could use `template` element :

```
   <TreeView 
                v-bind:item="treeData"
                v-on:make-folder="makeFolder"
                v-on:add-item="addItem">
     <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
        <Bookmark v-bind="slotProps.individualBookmark"></Bookmark>
    </template>
      </TreeView>
```

Comment: Thank you, this finally renders the child folder as a folder. Do you know how I could render the bookmarks within the child folder though? The child folder doesn't show the bookmarks that it contains.

Comment: you're welcome, please check my edited answer where i used template element to render the slot content

Comment: That didn't seem to work, here is a [picture](https://imgur.com/LxZsLAI) of what I am talking about. The child folder looks like it is expanded but it's not displaying the bookmarks that it contains. Also, for some reason when I click the [-] button on child folder, it retracts the whole tree, when it's only supposed to retract the bookmarks within the child folder.

Comment: could you provide some codepen codesandbox sample in order to debug it

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-wilbur-8dreq?file=/src/App.vue) is all of my code. Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: i'm doing my best to find the issue but i can't figure it out, tomorrow i will try again to debug it

Comment: In case it may be easier for you, I have posted this in a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108178/treeview-in-vue-not-rendering-subfolder-content-correctly).