# TreeView in Vue not rendering subfolder content correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, treeview, vue-component

I'm trying to build a `TreeView` from scratch in Vue. [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-wilbur-8dreq) is my code so far.

The first problem I'm encountering is that the content of the subfolders (like `child folder 1`) is not being displayed. The second problem is that minimizing the subfolders minimizes the whole treeview.

Could anyone help me understand why these two errors in functionality are occurring and how to fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your code only dealed with the first level of your folders, you should recursively revoke your tree components to deal with child folders. please refer to below article.

https://itnext.io/recursion-for-nested-tree-structure-components-in-vue-1cb600005475

2. your code is using one param (isOpen) to toggle minimizing all folders, so if isOpen is false, all folders minimized; you should use item.isOpen to deal with different item;

```
treeData: {
        name: "My Tree",
        isOpen: true,
        children: [
          { name: "hello" },
          { name: "wat" },
          {
            name: "child folder",
            isOpen: false,
            children: [
              {
                name: "child folder 1",
                isOpen: false,
                children: [{ name: "hello" }, { name: "wat" }]
              },
              { name: "hello" },
              { name: "wat" },
              {
                name: "child folder 2",
                isOpen: false,
                children: [{ name: "hello" }, { name: "wat" }]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
```

Comment: In line 31 of TreeView.vue , which is `<span v-if="isFolder">[{{ isOpen ? '-' : '+' }}]</span>` , I tried replacing `isOpen` with `child.isOpen`, but I still can't get the child folder to expand.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-booth-q3x4p?file=/src/components/TreeView.vue here is a rough example. maybe some errors. just for reference