# A problem with displaying required values, based on vue.js templates

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem with displaying wanted value based on onclick event. Value comes from an object in bookData array:

```
this.bookData.push(
            {
            avalable: true, 
            titles: [title, id],
            author: authors,
            descriptions: [description, id]
            })
```

I've typed a code with purpose of displaying descriptions value with onclick event using following vue.js templates. Everything needs to be related with this object (values in his keys are fetched from a google books API)  Here is the code:

```
//bookData == books  when transfered to the child component...



 <section  v-for="(bookTitle, index) in books"
      v-bind:key="index"
      
      >
    <button
      :ref="'el'+ index"
      @click="hidden = !hidden"
      class="list-group-item"
      v-if="bookTitle.titles"
    >{{bookTitle.titles[0]}}
    </button>
    <p v-if="!hidden">   
      {{
        bookTitle.titles[id] == bookTitle.descriptions[id] ?
        "'DESCRIPTION:'\n" + bookTitle.descriptions :
        console.log("it works")
        }}
      </p>
```

...

```
data() {
      return {
       hidden: true,
      }
    }
```

The problem is when I click on random button, It displays all description values Bellow of all button elements. It needs to display only a description which is in line with a value (or `innerHTML`) that stands on a button which is clicked in that moment. So, wanted description needs to be shown bellow clicked button, only once.

If there's any solution (maybe a method inside of `methods:{}`), any help or advice, you are welcome. I'm new with vue.js.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are using one param hidden to control all elements.
you should change the object as below and use item.hidden to deal with different item;

```
            {
            avalable: true, 
            hidden: true,
            titles: [title, id],
            author: authors,
            descriptions: [description, id]
            }
```

please refer to this issue:
[TreeView in Vue not rendering subfolder content correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108178/treeview-in-vue-not-rendering-subfolder-content-correctly/63109081#63109081)

Comment: Thx, but I'm still confused in comparing a logic of my problem whit an issue you wanted me to refer to.

Comment: the issue's second problem is similar to yours~